# Executing JQuery functions on DOM ready...from inside a module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module, scope

I have some experimental input checking Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var check_stuff = function(elem){
    //...code to check stuff
  };

  // grab every input element with a checkable class
  $('input.checkable').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function(){
      if check_stuff(elem) {
        $(this).submit();   // submit if passes checks
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Which works.  However, I'm concerned this is polluting the global space.  So if 'check_stuff' function is defined somewhere in jQuery or by another module sharing $, I have effectively just overridden it.  Is that correct?

If I remove the $ on the first line:

```
(function(){
```

Then I believe I am creating a standard javascript anonymous function, which effectively isolates check_stuff.  However, the:

```
$(this).click(function(){
```

...no longer executes on DOM ready (since it is executed as soon as its evaluated). I've tried wrapping it in jQuery(document).ready to no-effect.

Whats the right way of creating a module that executes a block of code on ready?

Comment: Thanks to everybody who posted, you all generally were on the same (correct) wavelength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a [`self-executing anonymous function`](http://briancrescimanno.com/2009/09/24/how-self-executing-anonymous-functions-work/). This code will run, and all variables included within this function will only exist within the local scope of that function. The `()` after the function definition will execute the function immediately.

Format:

```
(function(){

})();
```

Place that in the dom ready & you'll be good to go.

```
$(function(){

    (function(){
        //your code for the module
    })();

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VZ2ay/2/

Answer (score 1):

`$(func)` is short for `jQuery(document).ready(func)`. If you omit the jQuery constructor, `$`, an ordinary function is created. To invoke this function, add parentheses after the function, to invoke it:

```
(function(){
  ....
})(); //Parentheses to invoke the function

//Another option
(function(){...}())

//Illegal method (error):
function(){...}()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the "right way", but why not do something like:

```
(function($){
    // ...
    $(function(){
        // code that you want to run when the dom finishes loading
    });
    // ...
}(jQuery));
```

---

**Edit (for explanation)**:
   What this does is it creates a closure in js that passes in jQuery as a parameter, so that you can continue to use $ within the closure to reference jQuery like you're used to.  Within the closure you can create variables that your module needs.  These will not be accessible outside of the closure, so you're not polluting the global namespace.

Inside of this is the jQuery ready function you're used to.  Here is where you'd call the code which you want to run after the dom has completed loading.

**Update**: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/D6Hax/ to see this in action.

Answer (score 1):

[updated after reviewing comment]

I still don't think you're polluting global namespace with your original code.

```
var foo = "I am outside!";
var bar = "I am outside!";

$(function() {
    var foo = "I am in jQuery!";
    bar = "I am in jQuery!";
});

setTimeout(function() {
    alert('foo says: '+foo);
    alert('bar says: '+bar);
}, 5000);
```

foo and bar are in the global namespace. In the document ready function, adding 'var' before foo marks it as a local variable. This is shown to be true because the global version of 'foo' does not get updated. By omitting the 'var' on bar, we implicitly use the global namespace, so the existing variable IS updated.

Comment: This works, but any code he has inside of there will have to wait for the entire dom to finish loading before it can execute.

Comment: Updated the answer to address comment

Answer (score 1):

I might be full of it by this answer, but something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
  (function(){
   var check_stuff = function(elem){
     //...code to check stuff
   };

   // grab every input element with a checkable class
   $('input.checkable').each(function(i) {
     $(this).click(function(){
       if check_stuff(elem) {
         $(this).submit();   // submit if passes checks
       }
     };
   });
  )
});
```

You are still creating an anonymous function that will run after the DOM ready event.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this link http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

```
myModule = (function(){
     //functions/variables here does not pollute global namespace
})();
```

you can call myModule initialize function for example on your document ready